# Count the rows comparing the dates of 2 cells

Tags: date, google-sheets

I have an google sheets spreadsheet full of book data. Cells that matter are:
S = "read" or "abandoned-dnf" status
O - date read in the form of mm/dd/yyyy
M = Publication year of the book, in the form of yyyy

I want to do a COUNTIF based on whether the read/dnf book (cell S), was read (cell O) in the same year (or earlier, in the case of advanced reader copies) as it was published (cell M).

What I have isn't working:
(just read books):

```
=COUNTIFS(GRData!$S:$S, "read", GRData!$O:$O, "<="&YEAR(GRData!$M:$M))
```

It just returns 0.

(read or DNF books)

```
=COUNTIFS(GRData!S:S, {"read", "abandoned-dnf"}, GRData!$O:$O, "<="&YEAR(GRData!$M:$M))
```

The second one I have (read books that were not read in the same year as it was published) does seem to work:

```
=COUNTIFS(GRData!S:S, {"read", "abandoned-dnf"}, GRData!$O:$O, ">"&YEAR(GRData!$M:$M), GRData!$M:$M, "<"&YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each criteria specified in `countifs()` should be a value rather than a range of values.

Since column `GRData!O2:O` contains dates such as `2023-11-14`, you should apply `year()` to that column instead of column `GRData!M2:M` that contains integers such as `2023`.

To compare the value in each row to another value in a different column in a row-by-row fashion, use `filter()`, like this:

```
=counta(iferror(filter( 
  GRData!S2:S, 
  regexmatch(GRData!S2:S, "(?i)read|abandoned-dnf"), 
  year(GRData!O2:O) <= GRData!M2:M 
)))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292).

The question specifies the [date](/questions/tagged/date) tag. See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).